# RecyclerView Android Dynamic Height

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

I am looking at creating dynamic heights in my RecyclerView to be responsive across all devices. Currently this works fine but for the first two rows at the start I have a double cell and the height of these two rows gets set to the first cell. I want instead this cell on both the first and second row to match the height of the last cell and become a rectangle. I have tried a few ways but none seem to work I am not sure where the problem is but I hope someone can show me. I will attach screenshots and the code below.

[image]

**SquareLayout.java**

```
public class SquareLayout extends LinearLayout {

    public SquareLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int width, int height) {
       // int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        //int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        // note we are applying the width value as the height
        //if(width>=370){
        //    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec/2);
       // }
       // else{
        //    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
      //  }

        super.onMeasure(width, width);

       // Log.d("int","int is: "+ width);

    }

}
```

**DataAdapter.java**

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android;
    private Context context;


    public DataAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android) {
        this.android = android;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
//        int width = viewHolder.tv_android.getMeasuredWidth() / 2; //returns -1
        Log.d("MYINT", "value: " + i);
        //Picasso.with(context).load(android.get(i).getAndroid_image_url()).resize(240, 120).into(viewHolder.img_android);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return android.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private LinearLayout testheight;
        private ImageView img_android;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

        }
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String android_version_names[] = {
            "test1",
            "test2",
            "test3",
            "test4",
            "test5",
            "test6",
            "test7",
            "test8",
            "test9",
            "test10"
    };

    private final String android_image_urls[] = {
            "http://example.com/images/test.png",
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initViews();
    }
    private void initViews(){


        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),3);


        ArrayList<AndroidVersion> androidVersions = prepareData();
        ((GridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                if (position == 0 || position == 2) {

                    return 2; // ITEMS AT POSITION 1 AND 6 OCCUPY 3 SPACES
                }

                else {
                    return 1; // OTHER ITEMS OCCUPY ONLY A SINGLE SPACE
                }
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), androidVersions);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> prepareData(){

        ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android_version = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<android_version_names.length;i++){
            AndroidVersion androidVersion = new AndroidVersion();
            androidVersion.setAndroid_version_name(android_version_names[i]);
            androidVersion.setAndroid_image_url(android_image_urls[i]);
            android_version.add(androidVersion);
        }
        return android_version;
    }
}
```

**row_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<example.SquareLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:background="@color/reloadedpurple"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</example.SquareLayout>
```

Comment: You can use **[StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-recyclerview.html)**

Comment: @NileshRathod This is not the same. I want the top row to all be the same height, just half of what it is now. e.g to match the end cell in the row.

Comment: @NileshRathod the first cell should be a rectangle and match the height of the smaller squares.

Comment: I am not exactly clear on what you are trying to do. I will suggest that you take a look at [`FlexboxLayout`](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) as an alternate approach. There is a `FlexboxLayoutManager` for `RecyclerViews`.